# How to select an existing object for a required relationship in MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5.1

### My domain classes:

```
public class Site
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; } // Required
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

### SiteCreate View contains only the following textbox:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteId)
```

### When I PostBack, an exception is thrown, as indicated below in SiteController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="SiteId,Name")] Site site)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Sites.Add(site);
        db.SaveChanges(); // ***Error Here***!!!
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
        return View(site);
}
```

It is obvious that exception is due to missing required "`Address`" object.

I want to select an existing "`Address`" object and include it in "`Site`" entity.

I have used a JQuery dialog box in my View to select an existing "`AddressId`" from the database.

My question is how to plug that "`Address`" object to "`Site`" in my View?
Or else pass it to the controller and plug it to "`Site`" entity?

Please Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is going to be looking for an `input` element with the `name` attribute set to `Address.AddressId` when it attempts to rebuild your model.

Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="Address.AddressId" value="" id="address" />
```

or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.AddressId, new { @id="address"})
```

to your form, then set it's value to whatever you need via jQuery.

An easy way to ensure you have the correct syntax for model binding is to simply add an 
`EditorFor(m => m.Address.AddressId)` and then checking what it generates for the name attribute on that input element

Comment: But we don't have an `Address` object in the view.  We just have one property of it.

Comment: you're right, a reference to the property is needed

Comment: i think you will need to modify your controller to `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="SiteId,Name,AddressId")] Site site)` for it to recognize `AddressId`

Comment: Thanks @Jonesy it worked for me! Firstly, I had to remove the binding with `Address` in my controller:
`public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SiteId,Name")] Site site)` 
otherwise the controller is expecting an `Address`upon PostBack. After receiving the PostBack I bind it back again to the `Site` entity:
`db.Entry(site.Address).State = EntityState.Added;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way or another, you'll need to put it into a hidden `<input />` element.  I'm not familar with the details of the `[Bind]` attribute, but I think there's a way to name to input to say "This is the addressId of the Address of the Site".  If not, just make it anouther parameter to the Create action and assign it in there.